# Displaying One Category Only On Wordpress Blog Page

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I did a lot of searching but I couldn't seem to get any results to work with my particular code. I was wondering how I could make this WordPress blog loop only bring up posts from category 183.

```
<?php // Display blog posts on any page
$temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=10' . 
'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can already limit the posts added to the query to only use category id 183 like this, if you don't want to include any children of the category:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__in' => 183 ) );
```

Or like this, if you want to include children of the category:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 183 ) );
```

For more information, you can take a look at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Try this below examples, you can the result from both code.

```html
<ul class="posts">
 <?php query_posts('cat=5'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <li><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 
 <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

------------- OR --------------

```html
<?php
$current_cat_id  = '10';
$showposts = 10;
$args = array('cat' => $current_cat_id, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => $showposts,'post_status' => 'publish');
query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>      
    <div class="timeline">
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_content();?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php _e('No Posts Sorry.'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that.

```
<?php // Display blog posts on any page
$temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array('cat'=>183,'posts_per_page'=>10);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you add your code? Did you create a template for your blog? 
You better add your query modification on [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)
 instead of messing with global `$wp_query`
e.g.

```
function _modify_blog_query( $query ) {

    // Run only on the blog page
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) { 

        // Additional Query here
        $query->query_vars['cat'] = 183; 
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 10; 
    }

}

// hook the the function on pre_get_posts
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', '_modify_blog_query' );
```